# Finding the Sum of a Geometric Series in Finance

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, geometric-series

I have been stuck on these two problems forever, I have tried using the Sum of a Finite Geometric Series formula, but I cannot get to the intended final product of 200(1.005^(n)-1). I even double checked to make sure the -1 did not have to be in the exponent, I am just at wits end! For clarification, I need help with solving Questions 5 and 6. [Mathematics of Loans Q5 and Q6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENqWZ.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that's only the part in paretheses from (4), not the full answer.

Are you using $1 + r + r^2 + \cdots + r^k = \dfrac{r^{k+1}-1}{r-1}$ ?

In this case, $r=1.005$, so $\dfrac1{r-1} = \dfrac1{0.005} = 200$.

You would also use $k=n-1$, so $r^{k+1}-1 = r^n - 1$.

Putting it together, you do indeed get the answer they suggest.